# char* issue in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, char

Why this fragment of code does not work? I know that all entered strings have length less than 20 symbols.I do not use **std::string** because I want to learn how to use char*

```
#include <map>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

map <char*,int> cnt;

int main() 
{
    char ans[20];
    int n,mx = 0;

    scanf("%d\n",&n);
    for ( int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        char str[20];
        gets(str);
        cnt[str]++;
     }
    for ( auto i = cnt.begin(); i != cnt.end(); i++ )
        puts(i->first);
 }
```

Comment: Flush your input buffer (`\n` is there left unread by previous `scanf`).

Comment: "Why this fragment of code does not work?" -- What is not working??

Comment: Show the declaration of `cnt`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's be clear that your code has a lot of undefined behavior.  I tried running your code and here is what I saw on my machine.  You should tell us what your behavior was though because it's impossible to say what's going on for you otherwise.

First off, here was my program input.

```
3
hello
world
cat
```

And the output...

```
cat
```

`char str[20]` is a memory address, and that address is being reused by the compiler.  Let's say that memory address is `0xABCD`.

So on the first iteration, the map contains one element which is { 0xABCD, 1 }.  On the second iteration it contains the same element with its value incremented, {0xABCD, 2}.  On the third iteration it contains {0xABCD, 3}.  Then when you go to print the map, it finds only one element in the map, and prints that memory address.  This memory address happens to contain the word "cat", so it prints cat.

But this behavior is not reliable.  The array `char str[20]` doesn't exist outside of the for loop, so sticking it into `map <char *, int> cnt` and even worse *printing* the array outside the loop are both undefined behavior.

If you want your code to work, I suppose you could do this....

```
  for ( int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    char * str = new char[20];
    gets(str);
    cnt[str]++;
  }
  for ( auto i = cnt.begin(); i != cnt.end(); i++ )
    puts(i->first);

  for ( auto i = cnt.begin(); i != cnt.end(); i++ )
    delete[](i->first);
```

But really, the correct strategy here is to either....

1) Use std::string
or
2) Don't use std::map

If you want to use C strings beyond converting them to std::string, then program without the use of the C++ std library.  Stick to the C standard library.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `cnt` is `std::map<char*, ...>`. When you do `cnt[str]` you use pointer to local variable `str` as key, but `str` is only valid during single iteration. After that `str` is freed (semantically, optimizer may reuse it, but it is irrelevant here) and pointer to it is no longer valid.

Comment: How can this code be improved?

Comment: Easy way — use `std::map<std::string, ...>`, `std::string` will copy string contents for you and will keep it alive as long as needed.

Comment: Hard way — allocate string buffer for reading string in heap, but don't forget to manually free all keys after removing them from map.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple: when you allocate a C-style array as a local variable (`char str[20];`), it is allocated on the stack. It behaves just like any other object that you allocate as a local variable. And when it falls out of scope, it will be destroyed.

When you try to pass the array to the map in `cnt[str]`, the array name *decays to a pointer to the first element* (it implicitely converts an expression of type `char[20]` into an expression of type `char*`). This is something radically different than an array. The map only ever sees this single pointer and stores it as the key. The map does not dereference the pointer to find out what's behind it, it just uses the memory location.

To fix your code, you need to do two things:

1. You need to allocate memory for your strings on the heap, so that the `char*` remains valid after the end of the scope. The easiest way to do this is to use the `getline()` or `getdelim()` functions available in the POSIX-2008 standard: These beautiful two functions will actually do the `malloc()` call for you. However, you still need to remember to free the string afterwards.
2. Making the map aware that you are talking about strings and not about memory addresses is much harder to achieve. If you must use a map, you likely need to define your own `std::string`-like wrapper class. But I guess, since you are playing around with the `char*` to learn their use, it would be more prudent to use some other kind of list and program the logic to check whether the given string is already in the list. Could be an array of `char*`, probably sorted to save lookup time, or a linked list, or whatever you like. For ease, you can just use an `std::vector<char*>`, but don't forget to free your strings before letting the vector fall out of scope.